# Can we initialize instance variable through JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, variables, jtextfield

Can we initialize instance variable through JTextField? For example, lets x is an instance variable and i want to initialize its value when jbutton is clicked. i want to use this x, in another method. so can we update x.

```
public class CT extends JFrame{

JTextField txtf = new JTextField(20);
JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
int x;

CT(){
    setSize(600, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int a =Integer.parseInt(txtf.getText());
            display(a);
            x=a;
        }
    });
    add(btn);
    add(txtf);
    add(lbl);   
}

public void display(int s){
    System.out.println(s);

    System.out.println(x); //this display zero?? can we update it?
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new CT();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
x=a;
```

should be executed before the statement

```
display(a);
```

You are printing out the values of a and x before you 'initialize' x.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it displays `0` is that you call

```
display(a);
x=a;
```

Instead of

```
x=a;
display(a);
```

However, in either case, this is not initialization. This is simply assignment. The field `x` is not set to anything (well, it's 0, the default) when the constructor of `CT` is finished.

It's important to note that the code in `actionPerformed()` is not really called in the constructor, only created in it. So any assignments inside it are not considered "initialization".

What is the difference between an initialization and an assignment? If `x` was `final`, then the only place where you can put a value in it is

- Initializer. E.g.

  ```
  final int x = 15;
  ```
- Initialization block. E.g.

  ```
  final int x;

  {
      x = 15;
  }
  ```
- Inside a constructor.

So these are considered "initializations". All other assignments to a `final x`, in methods, in methods of nested classes etc. would fail.

Since you did not declare `x` as `final` you may not notice the difference between an initialization and an assignment, but what you have there in your code is definitely an assignment.